# can't display data form json object with Object.Keys and .map in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to change my API from containing array to containing object. I tried to map my object so I can use it on bootstrap card. it didn't show any error but it didn't show any contained item too. How can I fix this ?

here's my object example:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Monitor LG 24 Inch",
            "description": "Ini adalah sebuah monitor",
            "weight": 1,
            "price": 13,
            "stock": 2,
            "datetime_added": "2022-02-21T12:27:06.878894Z",
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/BurnBly.jpg",
            "brand": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "LG",
                "image": null
            },
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Electronic",
                "image": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My React App:

```
const Categorized = () => {
 const [getData, setGetData] =useState();

 useEffect(()=>{ 
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/products/?format=json`).then(res => {
        const products = Object.keys(res.data);
        setGetData(products);
        console.log({products})
      })
 }, []);

  return (
    <Row>
      {getData && getData.map(product =>{
        const {id, category,image} = product;
        return(
        <Col lg={3} className="d-flex">
          <Card key={id} className="productlist flex-fill">
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} width="50%"/>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{category}</Card.Title>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        )
      })}
    </Row>
  )
}

export default Categorized
```

Comment: ```Object.keys(res.data)``` will only gives you the array with object keys like ```['count', 'next', 'previous', 'results']``` . So you are mapping this array with keys so you won't find id or category or image.. More on Object.keys here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: how can I get the other object Key ?

Comment: Do you want to display the data that are inside ```results``` ? Could you give some brief on your expected result?

Comment: yeah i'm expecting to be able to display the data inside results and use it on my Card Component

Comment: You are trying to make ```<Card.Title>{category}</Card.Title>``` but whereas category is an object inside results. How you want that to be rendered?

Comment: Anyhow check this, https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-northcutt-ixeufp

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your usage of the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method:

```javascript
const products = Object.keys(res.data); // here
setGetData(products);
```

From MDN:

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property **names**, iterated in the same order that a normal loop would.

The `products` array you are getting is of the names of the properties, like `"count"`, `"next"`, `"previous"`, `"results"`, etc.

However, in your `.map()` loop, you expect an object with properties `id`, `category`, and `image`.

```javascript
{getData && getData.map(product => {
  const {id, category, image} = product; // these properties don't exist - `product` is a string
  // ...
})}
```

To fix this, use the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method instead:

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop.

```javascript
const products = Object.values(res.data); // correct
setGetData(products);
```

Note that you still may get errors due to consuming the data wrong in your `.map()` call. You may need to loop over `getData.results` rather than just `getData`.

```javascript
{getData && getData.results.map(product => {
  const {id, category, image} = product; // these properties don't exist - `product` is a string
  // ...
})}
```

Comment: it still shows error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') do you know why ?

Comment: init `getData` with an empty array will solve the problem
`const [getData, setGetData] =useState([]);`

Comment: @KimSan I'm not sure what the response object is supposed to contain so I can't be certain, but it seems that `getData.results` is `undefined`. Try `console.log(getData)` to see what's going on.